# Prove $\prod_1^\infty (1+p_n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, infinite-product

Let $p_{2n-1} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}}$, and $p_{2n} = \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Prove $\prod_1^\infty (1+p_n)$ converges.

By numerical simulations, it appears to converge (to something around $0.759$). However, I'm not sure how to prove this. I know we can skip the first term since it's $0$. Then we can write it in the following form.

\begin{align*}
\prod_1^\infty (1+p_n) &= \prod_1^\infty \left(1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)  \\
&=  \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)...
\end{align*}
Any thoughts?

Comment: Hint : $1+n^{-1/2}+n^{-1} = (1+n^{-1/2})(1+\frac{n^{-1}}{1+n^{-1/2}})$

Comment: It's not apparent to me how that is useful.

Comment: Then expand $\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)$ and use that $\sqrt{2n(2n+1)} = 2n+O(n^{-1})$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $a_{2n-1}=-1/\sqrt{n}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ Show that $\prod (1+a_n)$ converges but that $\sum a_n$ diverges.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284641/let-a-2n-1-1-sqrtn-for-n-1-2-dots-show-that-prod-1a-n-converges)

Comment: According to your def'n, $p_2=2, p_3=-1/\sqrt 2, p_4=1/2+1/\sqrt 2,$ etc.  which does not match what follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\prod\limits_{k=2}^{2n}(1+p_k) = \prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}(1+p_{2k-1})(1+p_{2k}) = \prod\limits_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{k} +\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)  = \prod\limits_{k=2}^{n} \left(1- \dfrac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}\right)$$

It is also known that for any sequence $\{a_k\}$ such that $\forall k \geqslant 2: 0 \leqslant a_k < 1$:

$$\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n} \left(1- a_k\right) \leqslant e^{-\sum\limits_{k=2}^n a_k}$$

The inequality above is true because $1 -x \leqslant e^{x}$ for $0 \leqslant x < 1$.

Hence, for $a_k = \dfrac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}$:

$$\prod\limits_{k=2}^{n} \left(1- \dfrac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}\right) \leqslant \exp\left(-\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \dfrac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}\right)$$

Thus, to finish the proof it is enough to note that $\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \dfrac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}$  converges.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got $1-1/k\sqrt{k}$ in the first line.  It seems like you're missing a term.

Comment: I'm confused too. Maybe I'm entirely misinterpreting the problem. It seems like we have two different products in mind

Comment: @mathematician This is correct. I edited the answer and hope now it is more clear. Here is the computation: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-1%2Fsqrt(k))(1%2B1%2Fk%2B1%2Fsqrt(k))

Comment: @antsatsui this is because your definition of $p_{2n}$ in the first line doesn't match what you put towards the end of your post.  This answer uses the definition you gave in the first line.

Comment: Both you and the proposer should be taking the product for $k\geq 2$, as $1+p_1=0. $ In your last line you are (implicitly) using the (elementary) theorem that if $0\leq a_n<1$ for all $n$ then $\prod_n(1-a_n)>0 \iff \sum_na_n<\infty.$

Comment: @mathematician Why? I don't see where it doesn't match the definition from the question.

Comment: @user254665 I agree about  $k \ge 2$ and edited the answer accordingly. As regards to the theorem you mentioned, I more or less proved it showing that the last inequality (involving exponent) holds. So I wouldn't say that this fact is used "implicitly".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure if this can be made rigorous, but maybe you can take it as a starting point.

\begin{align*}\log \Pi(1+p_n)= \sum \log((1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}})(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}))\\\approx\sum \log((1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}})(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}))\approx\sum \log(1-\frac{1}{2n})\approx \sum -\frac{1}{2n} \rightarrow \infty\end{align*}

using
$\log(1+\frac{1}{n})\approx \frac{1}{n}$

---

Actually there appears to be a cancellation that makes it so I can't neglect $1/2n$ the way I did.  $(1+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}})(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}) =1+(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}})+(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n)(2n+1)}})-\frac{1}{2n\sqrt{2n+1}}$ and asymptotically the first grouped terms are $\approx \frac{1}{2(2n)^{3/2}}$ ... in short, the product converges.

Comment: For making it rigorous you need to use that as $x \to 0$ : $\log(1+x) = x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$ (we stop at $x^3$ because $\sum_n n^{-3/2}$ converges)